# Is availability of port 80 a must for a SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, 2007, iis, port

I have got this Dev env where only read access is provided. While browsing through default ports, i found that port 80 is assigned for Commerce Server and not SharePoint. So my query is **if any other web app (not related to SharePoint) is configured on port 80, Do we have to configure another port manually during SharePoint farm setup wizard ( when it creates a default web app) ?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You configure the port when you create your web applications, not during installation or configuration.  But, the farm setup wizard will probably try to set up the initial web app on port 80, so just skip that and create the web app manually through Central Admin.  There, you can specify the port.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So port 80 is not a must for SharePoint web app, rite? Also, if an application is already configured at port 80, then when Farm setup wizard runs, will it give set up the web app on any other port or do we have to skip it and create manually through CA?

Comment: you need to skip it during wizard or otherwise it shall  generate issues. afterwards you shall be able to create any web-app, using your own Host-Headers if you wish to use port 80.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint does not require a Web Application to be listening on port 80, but I would suggest looking at host header mode so you can have multiple IIS sites on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we can extend our web application to different port by extending web application.

How to do the same has been explained in [changing-sharepoint-default-port-80-to-another-port-79](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/1159-changing-sharepoint-default-port-80-to-another-port-79)